# Import quality profile or rules from SonarQube to SonarLint in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

We are using `SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.9.4 (build 35981)` on a remote server where we have created few quality profiles for java code. But I want to import these profile and rules to my `SonarLint` in eclipse so that I will be able to fix issues while writing code eventually saving time and iterations.
Can this be done ?

Comment: I believe you should be using SonarLint's [Connected Mode](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-eclipse/wiki/Connected-Mode).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but in Eclipse you may:
Right click in your project -> SonarLint -> Bind to SonarQube or SonarCloud...
After you just need to pass connection information. Automatically the rules from actived quality profiles will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the feature you're looking for is not implemented yet.

You can vote for it here so it might come soon(er): https://portal.productboard.com/sonarsource/4-sonarlint/c/198-import-export-local-ruleset

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35300794)

Comment: @MichaelM. how is this not an answer? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425692/11107541